# Photoshop Action to insert text with a box around it

Tags: textbox, action, photoshop

I have a 92 page catalogue (one image per page, multiple products per image) and no product codes on the image for each product.

Does anyone know of a photoshop action to allow entry of a stock code (<15chars text), that will create a filled, outline box with the text inside? It will be awful to have to do them by hand - there are hundreds and hundreds of products.

Answer (score 0):

If all images have the same code, you could record the action which basically creates a macro of your activity for a single image. (Look for the record/playback buttons on the actions pane.)

If all the images have different codes, you might be better off writing (or commissioning) a small script to process the images, such as a PHP script with GD or C# and a graphics object; in both cases reading from a file so it applies the correct code to the image. However this method wouldn't give you an Adobe Photoshop document at the end of the day with an editable text box; it would be a flattened image (such as a TIFF) with the product code already rendered as part of the image.

Comment: Unfortunately, all codes are different, and I need it to be a psd at the end of the process. My current workaround was to recall a favour owed at the print shop next door, who loaded a previous catalogue with stock codes into the document feeder and scanned the lot! Sometimes the brute-force way is the only way forward !